# Theorem 2.30 (Rudin's PMA) but for closed sets.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Theorem 2.30 (closed-sets)**: Suppose $Y \subset X$. A subset $E$ of $Y$ is closed relative to $Y$ if and only if $E = Y \cap G$ for some closed subset $G$ of $X$.

The above theorem is based on the following lines (found under the section titled **Definition 3.23** in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis)

> ... The property of being open thus depends on the space in which $E$ is embedded. The same is true of the property of being closed.

**Proof**: Let $E = E_Y = E_X$, where the subscript is read as "relative to", i.e. $E_Y$ is the set $E$ relative to Y. Let $N_{r,Z}(p) = \{q\in Z \,|\, d(p,q) < r\}$, i.e. the neighborhood of $p$ of radius $r$ relative to $Z$. Also, let $closed\_subset(P, Q)$ denote that $P$ is a closed subset of $Q$. Then, we need to

**Lemma**: Let $E \subset Y \subset X$, then $E_Y'\subset E_X'$, where $E_Z'$ is the set of all limit-points of set $E$ relative to set $Z$, for any set $Z$.

- **Proof:** let $\exists x \in E_Y'$ such that $x \notin E_X'$. This implies the following,

  1. $\exists x \in E_Y' \implies \forall r>0\quad N_{r,Y}(x)\cap (E\backslash \{x\}) \neq \phi$, i.e. every neighborhood of $x$ in the set $Y$ has some element of $E_Y$ not equal to $x$.
  2. We have $x \notin E_X' \implies \exists r>0\quad N_{r,X}(x)\cap (E\backslash \{x\}) = \phi$. But $N_{r, Y}(x) \subset N_{r, X}(x)$, since $x\in Y \subset X$. This contradicts the above statement!

  Hence the lemma is proved.

**Proof (part-1)**: Prove the following

$\qquad closed\_subset(E, Y) \implies \exists G\subset X: E = G\cap Y \text{ and } closed\_subset(G, X)$

The antecedent implies that $E = E\cup E_Y'$. Let $G = E \cup E_X'$, therefore $G$ is closed subset of $X$. And, based on the above lemma we can write, $E_X' = E_Y' \cup E_X''$, where $E_X''$ is the set of limit-points of $E$ relative to $X$, that are only found in $X$. Then, we have
\begin{align*}
E & = G\cap Y \\
& = (E\cup E_X')\cap Y \\
& = (E\cap Y)\cup ((E_Y'\cup E_X'')\cap Y) \\
& = (E\cap Y)\cup(E_Y'\cap Y)\cup(E_X'' \cap Y) \\
& = E\cup E_Y' \cup \phi \qquad\text{(eq.1)}\\
& = E \\
\end{align*}

**Proof (part-2)**: Prove the following

$\qquad \exists G\subset X: E = G\cap Y \text{ and } closed\_subset(G, X) \implies closed\_subset(E, Y)$

Let $G = E\cup E_X'$, therefore $G$ closed subset of $X$. Then, from eq.1 above, we have $E = E\cup E_Y'$, therefore, $E$ is closed subset of $Y$.

**Question**: Is this proof valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is good (in any *metric* space) except for the very final point.

You can't just put $G=E\cup E'_X$, you are just told that "there is" some closed $G\subseteq X$, you have no control over what it specifically equals. I've written a fix to that that's in the same style as the rest of your proof:

> If $E=G\cap Y$, then $E\subseteq G$, so $E'_X\subseteq G'_X\subseteq G$ since $G$ is closed. Hence $E\cup E'_X\subseteq G$, and $(E\cup E'_Y)\cup E''_X\subseteq G$, so after intersecting with $Y$ you find that $(E\cup E'_Y)\subseteq G\cap Y=E$, thus $E'_Y\subseteq E$ and $E$ is closed in $Y$.

You might want to do this in *any* topological space, if you've encountered that notion yet. The proof is quite nice, using no metrics.

---

If $X$ is a space and $Y\subseteq X$ a subspace, and $E\subseteq Y$ is closed in $Y$, that means there is a $Y$-open $U\subseteq Y$ with $E=Y\setminus U$. If $U$ is $Y$-open, that means by definition there is an $X$-open $W\subseteq X$ with $U=Y\cap W$. So: $$E=Y\setminus(Y\cap W)=Y\cap(X\setminus W)$$

And $G:=X\setminus W$ is $X$-closed, so we are done in that direction.

In the other, if $G$ is $X$-closed and $E:=Y\cap G$, then note: $$Y\setminus E=Y\cap(X\setminus G)$$And $W:=X\setminus G$ is $X$-open, so $Y\setminus E$ is $Y$-open, so $E$ must be $Y$-closed by definition.